# Removing a property in JSON with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, http, objectmapper, payload

In a Java/Spring application, I have a POJO/bean. Let's call it `CourseRequest`. It is converted/serialized into a string and sent out in a PUT REST request. The conversion is done using `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`. The sending is done using `org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest`. See simplified code:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(...);
CourseRequest courseRequest = new CourseRequest(...);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String courseJson = null;
        
try {
    // convert to json.
    courseJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(courseRequest);
    request.addPayload(courseJson);
    request.send();
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    logger.error(e);
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    logger.error(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
```

I have run into a problem where I need to remove a property `instructorId` from the JSON/payload before sending the request. Obviously, I can't just naively remove the property in `CourseRequest` because the POJO/bean is used in other places too.

So, what is the best way to do it?

I can't use `@JsonIgnore` or alike annotations, because

- I want to remove the property only on some conditions;
- There are other requests elsewhere in the application which may want to keep the property

For initial thoughts:

- As a "hack", I can do a regex replace on the `courseJson` to remove the property after `mapper.writeValueAsString(courseRequest)` but I think that's not a very clean way to do it.
- I can parse the `courseJson` back into some kind of map and then remove the property but that's just clumsy.

P.S. I am using Jackson v1.9.13

Comment: Did you try adding a `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the property?

Comment: @daniu I can't do that, because (1) I want to remove the property only on some conditions; (2) there are other request scenarios in the application which may want to keep the property

Comment: set instructorId to null based on your condition and annotate instructorId with `@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` in pojo

Comment: @dkb so what happens if I want to include instructorId=null in other requests?